# Is the `id` returned by Azure OpenAI GPT model sensitive, or can I share it publicly without any issue?

Tags: gpt, privacy

When I call an Azure OpenAI GPT model e.g.:

```
#Note: This code sample requires OpenAI Python library version 1.0.0 or higher.
import json
import pprint
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = "https://xxxxxx.openai.azure.com/",
  api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  api_version="2023-07-01-preview"
)

message_text = [{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."}]
completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-4xxxxxxxx", 
  messages = message_text,
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=800,
  top_p=0.95,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
  stop=None
)

print('completion:\n')
pprint.pprint(completion)
```

the returned object has some `id` (which is `chatcmpl-xxxxxxxxx` in this example):

```
ChatCompletion(id='chatcmpl-xxxxxxxxx', choices=[Choice(finish_reason='stop', index=0, logprobs=None, message=ChatCompletionMessage(content='Great! How can I assist you today?', role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None), content_filter_results={'hate': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'self_harm': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'sexual': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'violence': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}})], created=1709313222, model='gpt-4', object='chat.completion', system_fingerprint='fp_xxxxx', usage=CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=9, prompt_tokens=18, total_tokens=27), prompt_filter_results=[{'prompt_index': 0, 'content_filter_results': {'hate': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'self_harm': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'sexual': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'violence': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}}}])
```

Is the `id` returned by Azure OpenAI GPT model sensitive, or can I share it publicly without any issue?